# How to create a to-do list in React without ref

Tags: reactjs

I intend to create a to-do list without using ref as in the many examples, but it isn't working.

The expected behavior is that upon entering an entry, it will show up at the top and upon clicking add, it will create an input box for entering an entry. Currently, upon entering the state returns undefined.

The code can be found below or in this [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ttpibw?file=todo.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import ToDo from './todo'
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: []
    };
  }

  onChange=(e)=>{
    const newToDos = [...this.state.todos]
    newToDos.push(e.target.value)
    this.setState({
      todos: newToDos
    })
  }

    onAdd=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      const newtodos=[...this.state.todos]
      this.setState({
        todos: newtodos.push("")
      })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.todos)
    return (
      <div>
        <p>All the to-dos include {this.state.todos}</p>
        <ToDo 
          todos={this.state.todos}
        />
        <form onSubmit={this.onChange}>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="add a new todo..."
          />
        </form>   
        <button onClick={this.onAdd}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And here is the todo.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default class ToDo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    const {todos, onChange}=this.props
    return (
      <div>
        {
          todos.map((todo, index)=>
          <div>
            {todo}
          </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your new todo in state when onChange input and add this into todos when click save.

I have forked and edit your sample.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nwtp5g?file=index.js

BTW: In your sample, `newtodos.push("")` will return the length of newtodos array, not the array after pushed.

```
onAdd=(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const newtodos=[...this.state.todos]
  this.setState({
    todos: newtodos.push("")
})
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

your code newtodos.push("")  dosent return array  so no map function:

```
    this.setState({
    todos: newtodos.push("")
  })
```

correct it something like this

```
    this.setState({
        todos: newtodos.concat("new value")
      })
```

Comment: What is the correction? Both snippet look the same except added formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code with

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import ToDo from './todo'
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      inputText: ""
    };
  }


    onAdd= () => {
      this.setState({
        todos: [...this.state.todos, this.state.inputText], textInput: ""
      })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.todos)
    return (
      <div>
        <p>All the to-dos include {this.state.todos}</p>
        <ToDo 
          todos={this.state.todos}
        />
        <form>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="add a new todo..."
            onChange={inputText => this.setState({inputText})} 
          />
        </form>   
        <button onClick={this.onAdd}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And in todo.js you can simply do

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default const ToDo = ({todos}) => {
  return(<div>
    {todos.map((todo, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        {todo}
      </div>))}
    </div>)}
```

as it do not contains any `state` associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with this code,

```
<form onSubmit={this.onChange}>
   <input 
       type="text" 
       placeholder="add a new todo..."
   />
</form>
```

Here you are adding `onSubmit` on form, which will never call because you don't have `submit` button.

you should do something like this,

```
<form>
 <input 
     type="text" 
     placeholder="add a new todo..."
     onChange={this.onChange}
     value={this.state.currentValue}
 />
</form>
```

```
onChange=(e)=>{
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
      currentValue: e.target.value
  })
}

onAdd=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      const newToDos = [...this.state.todos]
      newToDos.push(this.state.currentValue)
      this.setState({
         todos: newToDos,
         currentValue: ''
    })
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sevzn6?embed=1&file=index.js)

**Update**

In your `todo` component you have useless constructor, If you don't have state in a component or don't have any function to bind `this` don't add constructor.

You can remove the constructor.

Another thing is, you are not passing any `onChange` prop to `todo` component, so here you will get `undefined` for `onChange`.

```
const {todos, onChange}=this.props
```

You can also write this component as a functional component.